# Selecting multiple columns where the data in one column cannot be repeated

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay so I'm new to SQL and I've been trying to figures this out for awhile and not really getting anywhere.
I have a table named WaitingList with 3 columns - Customer_Name, Holiday, and Timestamp. I need to select the earliest timestamps for each different holiday with the name of the customer scheduled for that holiday.
So for example if I have..

```
CUSTOMER_NAME | HOLIDAY | TIMESTAMP   
Bill | Christmas | 2014-04-20  
Tom | Easter | 2014-04-19  
Kate | Christmas | 2014-04-24
```

I would like to get the ResultSet of..

```
CUSTOMER_NAME | HOLIDAY  
Bill | Christmas  
Tom | Easter
```

But I can't determine the appropriate statement.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: SELECT MAX(CUSTOMER_NAME),HOLIDAY,MIN(TIMESTAMP) FROM table GROUP BY HOLIDAY

Comment: @Mihai Is that supposed to be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`ODER BY TIMESTAMP DESC` gives you the earliest timestamps and use `GROUP BY HOLIDAY` to get each different holiday uniquely.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME ,HOLIDAY  FROM WaitingList GROUP BY HOLIDAY ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Comment: hmm this tells me: Column reference 'CUSTOMER_NAME' is invalid, or is part of an invalid expression.  For a SELECT list with a GROUP BY, the columns and expressions being selected may only contain valid grouping expressions and valid aggregate expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bcf2/6

```
select wl.CUSTOMER_NAME,
wl.HOLIDAY
FROM WaitingList wl
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT HOLIDAY,MIN(TIMESTAMP) as earliest_booking 
FROM WaitingList 
GROUP BY HOLIDAY
 )tab
on wl.TIMESTAMP = tab.earliest_booking
```

Which results in

[image]